# Xamarin Android - System.DllNotFoundException: android-pocketsphinx.so in release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, pocketsphinx

I am working on a Xamarin Forms Android app and using native libraries provided by 'pocketsphinx'.

Application works well in Debug mode but its throwing 'DllNotFoundException' when I run the application in Release mode.

The .so files are under lib/ folders and the build action set to 'AndroidNativeLibrary'.

Any inputs would be helpful.

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShmyrev. I will need to use this in a Xamarin application.

Comment: If you try to binding the java library pocketsphinx .

1.Open the pocketsphinx demo project on Android Studio
2.Make sure all the assets folder for pocketsphinx are the same name and path
3.Build!
4.The assets.lst and .md5 files (for each file) are being generated by the Android Studio
5.Copy those files to the visual studio project
And you can also install the package Rainbow.Xamarin.Pocketsphinx.Droid from nuget .